# Why doesn't doctest detect my tests?

Tags: python, doctest

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    '''
    This function parses a name according to following rules - 

    >>> Test().name('Kshitiz Sharma')
    Sharma, Kshitiz

    '''
    def name(self, name):
        name = name.split()
        return name[1] + ", " + name[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The output is -

```
4 items had no tests:
    __main__
    __main__.Test
    __main__.Test.__init__
    __main__.Test.name
0 tests in 4 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Where is my test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the docstring inside the method.

```
def name(self, name):
    '''
    This function parses a name according to following rules - 

    >>> name('Kshitiz Sharma')
    <BLANKLINE>

    '''
    pass
```

Also to run the test on a method correctly you'll need to actually instantiate the class to have access to the method during the test itself:

```
    >>> t = Test(); t.name('Kshitiz Sharma')
    <BLANKLINE>
```

Comment: @KshitizSharma [Python: using doctests for classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708178/python-using-doctests-for-classes)