# Executing Python doctest code

Tags: python, python-unittest, doctest

I have simple Python code that uses dockets

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708178/python-using-doctests-for-classes

class Test:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._number=number

    def multiply_by_2(self):
        """
        >>> t.multiply_by_2()
        4
        """
        return self._number*2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(extraglobs={'t': Test(2)})
```

I can use it with python interpreter:

```
> python simple.py
```

However, when I execute the code from doctest module, I get this error:

```
> python -m doctest simple.py
**********************************************************************
File "simple.py", line 10, in simple.Test.multiply_by_2
Failed example:
    t.multiply_by_2()
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1289, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "<doctest simple.Test.multiply_by_2[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        t.multiply_by_2()
    NameError: name 't' is not defined
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in simple.Test.multiply_by_2
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Why is this difference? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that when you execute via `doctest`, it is the `__main__` module compared to executing directly where your script's `if __name__ == '__main__'` block will execute.

I don't know of a good solution other than to put all the information you need in the docstring itself:

```
def multiply_by_2(self):
    """
    >>> t = Test(2)
    >>> t.multiply_by_2()
    4
    """
    return self._number * 2
```

This will have the added benefit that users who are *reading* your docstrings will know what's going on ... They won't have to stumble upon your `extraglobs` keyword to figure out what `t` is and how it was initialized.